# How to make IFrame fill width of screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page on a ASP.NET Web Forms site in which I load one or two IFrames next to each other. One to the left, and one loads to the right. If the one to the left does not need to be filled, only the one on the right needs to be loaded and be fullscreen size.

This used to work, but since I implemented the Bootstrap grid system the IFrames load in very small windows:

[image]

The code to accomplish this unwanted effect is loaded in a bootstrap `row` element with an inner `col-lg-12`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="workflow-content col-lg-12">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <asp:Button ID="CloseButton" runat="server" OnClick="CloseButton_Click" 
            SkinID="WorkflowNavigation" EnableViewState="False" 
             CausesValidation="False"  Text="Close" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Where the following code is injected:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" ID="Main" runat="server">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 pull-left" id="ScanFrame" runat="server">
            <iframe name="ifrmScan" id="ifrmScan" runat="server"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
            <iframe name="ifrm" id="ifrm" runat="server"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div><!--row-->
</asp:Content>
```

Programmatically it is accomplished that the left `ScanFrame` only loads if content is available.

So the unwanted effect is that the IFrames are very small, and that the right is always on the right, even when the left one is unavailable (this is quite logical looking at the CSS, the small width is not, although I think they are related).

Does anyone have any idea how I can accomplish the effect that both IFrames fills the half of the screen when both have content, and that the right is fullscreen when that is the only one with content? It is not necessary to use Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your iframe width to 100%. Your divs are the ones that set the structure correct? So let the iframes fill their space.

Update: iFrames are tricky when it comes to setting their dimensions, you may have to resort to setting their heights manually, or using some form of jQuery to set their sizes on the fly.

Comment: It works for the width! It fills the row-width. But the height is still the same size. Setting height= 100% on the IFrame makes the right one disappear.